# Android: Calling crop activity after taking photo

Tags: android, crop

I'm facing a problem with parsing a uri of taken photo to crop activity. In my application, users can take a photo or select one from gallery and then crop it and upload it. Everything sounds straightforward.

When pick from Gallery, Gallery app return an uri for selected photo like this:

```
content://media/external/images/media/20
```

I start crop activity with this uri by following code, everything seems ok:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
intent.setData(uri);
intent.putExtra("outputX", 96);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 96);
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
intent.putExtra("scale", true);
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);            
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CROP);
```

But when I take a photo, I can only know the photo's path like this:

```
file:///mnt/sdcard/iBet88.us/IMAGE_20120517_151606.jpg
```

and Crop Activity will not accept this uri.
I tried another way with Content Provider: add newly captured photo to ContentProvider, and then get new uri in sheme "content://..." from following code:

```
// TODO insert to Content Provider
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, avatarFilePathTmp.getPath());
contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PRIVATE, 0);
cr.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

// TODO get id from Content Provider
String[] projection = { 
    MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
};
String selectionClause = "" + MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " = ?";

String[] selectionArgs = {avatarFilePathTmp.getPath()};
Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    projection,
    selectionClause,
    selectionArgs,
    "");

Uri uri = null;    
if (null == mCursor) {

} else if (mCursor.getCount() < 1) {

} else {
    mCursor.moveToFirst();
    int id = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));

    String u = "content://media/external/images/media/" + id;

    // create new Uri
    uri = Uri.parse(u);
}
```

My new Uri is similar to uri from Gallery app, but when I start Crop Activity with new Uri, I get this Exception:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.android.camera.action.CROP dat=content://media/external/images/media/20 (has extras) }
```

***My questions:***
1. Why Crop Activity refuses to work with my new Uri, despite my new Uri and uri from Gallery App are the same "content://..."
2. How can I call Crop Activity to crop a photo in sdcard which I know its path only?

I tried to google but still no luck.
Sorry for my bad English. Thank you.

Comment: Did it work for you then?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had `intent.setType("image/*");` and it still didn't work...

What solved it for me was using:
`intent.setDataAndType(tempImageURI, "image/*");`

Good luck!

Comment: where and how do you use tempImageURI?

Comment: this answer is correct. I had intent.setType("image/*") and intent.setData(uri) on separate lines and only an image selected from gallery worked. Using setDataAndType(uri, "image/*") worked with other apps as well such as Astro and Dropbox.