# Android crop image in android 4.2.2

Tags: android

I want to crop image after capturing from camera.
I am using this code.

```
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
```

but it gives error: 
activity not found.
My android version is 4.2.2.

I also tried.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
```

but it opens the gallery not the captured image.

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632137/android-calling-crop-activity-after-taking-photo)

Comment: have a look at this .http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/07/how-to-crop-image-from-camera-and.html

Comment: i have checked this.but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code this will help you.

```
    //call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not support it)
Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    //indicate image type and Uri
cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
    //set crop properties
cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    //indicate aspect of desired crop
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    //indicate output X and Y
cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
    //retrieve data on return
cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
```

for more details 
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/capture-and-crop-an-image-with-the-device-camera/

Answer (score 0):

The below worked on my samsung galaxy s3. Check the snap shot

Use this for capture image with camera

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final int PICK_FROM_CAMERA = 1; 
ImageView iv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Button buttonCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    buttonCamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
        // call android default camera
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());
        // ******** code for crop image
        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);

        try {

        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

        }
        }
        });


}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA) {
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
    Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
    iv.setImageBitmap(photo);

    }
    }       
    }        
    }
```

Resulting snap shot

[image]

Comment: i used exact your code.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.example.crop/com.example.crop.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Can u post the code. coz it works on my phone and i runs 4.1.2. On what device are you testing?

Comment: i am testing it on emulator.